# Jenkins "Job status" shows success even if it has failed

Tags: bash, jenkins, amazon-s3

```
cd /app/jenkins/aws/Microservices/ABC-services
echo "Pushing JAR file to S3"
aws deploy push --application-name DocumentStore --s3-location s3://${Bucket_name}/ABC.zip --ignore-hidden-files

echo "Creating deployment using AWS code deploy"
deployid=$(aws deploy create-deployment --application-name DocumentStore --file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce  --deployment-group-name ABCgrp--s3-location bucket=${Bucket_name},bundleType=zip,key=ABC.zip)

stat=$(aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id ${deployid} --query 'deploymentInfo.status' --output text)
while [ "$stat" != "Succeeded" ]
do
    echo "Deployment status $stat"
    sleep 2m
    stat=$(aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id ${deployid} --query 'deploymentInfo.status' --output text)
    exit 0
done
echo "Deployment status $stat"

while [ "$stat" != "Failed" ]
do
echo "Deployment status $stat"
    sleep 2m
    stat=$(aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id ${deployid} --query 'deploymentInfo.status' --output text)
    exit 1
done
echo "Deployment status $stat"
```

---

Even when its failing still jenkins job is exiting with success. When it failed Jenkins job has to be fail & when its success it should be success.

Could you please help me on this?

Note: Success condition is working fine only failed condition not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is all wrong unless I have no clue what you are actually intending.

After `stat=$(...)`, you are not testing anything, just `exit 0`. Always.

You enter a loop, sleep 2m, exec a deploy, capture the result, do not test  the result and `exit 0`. Nothing else happens.

Try using  [shell options](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html) `set -vx` to see what actually happens: (V)erbose and (X)trace

**Update:** try this;

It should continue looping, checking every 2 minutes to see if Succeeded or Failed. But you might be better off referring to the [CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/get-deployment.html)  to see if say,
`deploymentOverview = "InProgress"`

otherwise, continue. Not a user of **aws** and not going to do the research for you.

```
stat=null
while [ "$stat" != "Succeeded" && "$stat" != "Failed" ]
do
    stat=$(aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id ${deployid} --query 'deploymentInfo.status' --output text)
    if [ "$stat" = "Succeeded" ]
    then 
       exit 0
    elif[ "$stat" = "Failed" ]
    then 
       exit 1
    fi
    echo "Deployment status $stat"
    sleep 2m
done

# ps: it will never get to here; it will take one of the exits.
echo "Deployment status $stat"
```

Comment: I have added full script now. Can you please check and suggest,

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? You appear to be attempting `aws deploy get-deployment` multiple times.

Comment: I am trying deployment through jenkins using Code deplpy with blue green approch & auto scaling.

Comment: I think you need to turn on verbose/trace logging so you can see what is actually executing. You have 3 identical deploy calls and 3 identical echos, surrounded by odd logic.

Comment: Can you share sample log from failed attempt ? hard to tell where to look, with so many possible errors